# How do I format the following to use ::ng-deep

Tags: html, css, angular

Using Angular11, angular/material

How do I format my CSS to use ::ng-deep, myClass1 and myClass2. I have a working CSS that uses the /deep/ and want to change it to use ::ng-deep. I also want to have html to use a CSS class.

**HTML**

```
<mat-slide-toggle class="myClass1 myClass2" (change)="setGrayscaleValue($event)"></mat-slide-toggle>
```

**CSS: (works)**

```
:host /deep/ .mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked:not(.mat-disabled) .mat-slide-toggle-bar {
    background-color: #1c84c670;
}
:host /deep/ .mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked:not(.mat-disabled) .mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
    background-color: #1c84c6;
}
```

**CSS (not working)**

```
.myClass ::ng-deep .mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked:not(.mat-disabled) .mat-slide-toggle-bar {
    background-color: #1c84c670;
}
.myClass ::ng-deep .mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked:not(.mat-disabled) .mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
    background-color: #1c84c6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following.

```html
.myClass::ng-deep{
  .mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked:not(.mat-disabled) .mat-slide-toggle-bar {
    background-color: #1c84c670;
  }
  .mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked:not(.mat-disabled) .mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
    background-color: #1c84c6;
  }
}
```

And if that alone doesn't do the trick, add !important too.

```html
.myClass::ng-deep{
      .mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked:not(.mat-disabled) .mat-slide-toggle-bar {
        background-color: #1c84c670 !important;
      }
      .mat-slide-toggle.mat-checked:not(.mat-disabled) .mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
        background-color: #1c84c6 !important;
      }
    }
```